# Order functions by growth rate

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

EDIT: I've revised my answer based on the comments

I've got this HW question which asks me to order a list of functions by their growth rate. The question also asks to indicate which ones have the same growth rate. Here are the functions:

- N
- sqrt(N)
- N^1.5
- N^2
- N log N
- N log log N
- N log^2(N)
- N log(N^2)
- 2/N
- 2^N
- 2^(N/2)
- 37
- N^3
- N^2logN

And here is my answer. Bolded functions are what I think are the same:

- 37
- sqrt(N)
- N^1.5
- N
- N log log N
- N log N
- N log^2(N)
- **N log (N^2)**
- **N^2 log N**
- N^2
- N^3
- **2^(N/2)**
- **2^(N)**
- 2/N

This question is really confusing me. Is my answer correct? I used Wolfram Alpha to graph the functions, but comparing the growths got very complicated.

EDIT: My revised answer.

2/N, 37, sqrt(N), N^1.5, N, N log log N, **N log N, N log N^2**, N^2log N, **Nlog^2(N), N^2**, N^3, **2^N, 2^(N/2)**

Comment: What's another way of writing `log(N^2)`?  What does that imply about the complexity of `N log(N^2)`?

Comment: Another hint: what is the limit of `2^n / 2^(n / 2)` as n approaches infinity? Does this limit help you tell if they're equal or not? Also, why do you say `2 / n` has the highest growth rate? what happens to it as `n` approaches infinity?

Comment: Have you tried plotting these?  You may be in for some surprises if you do...

Comment: @IVlad I initially had 2/N at the beginning, since it seems to have a negative growth rate, but then I confused myself. I've revised my answer a bit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is homework.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a work request

Answer (score 2):

I would answer:

- 2/N
- 37
- sqrt(N)
- N
- N log log N
- N log N
- N log N^2 (= 2N log N)
- N log^2(N)
- N^1.5
- N^2
- N^2log N
- N^3
- 2^(N/2)
- 2^N

Answer (score 1):

i am sure of following functions.

- N log(N^2) is not equal to N^2 log(N)
- N log(N^2) is equal to 2N log(N) which is N log(N)
- N log(2^N) is equal to N^2